# apply an aggregate result to all ungrouped rows of a dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

assume there is a dataframe as follows:

```
machine_id  | value
 1| 5
 1| 3
 2| 6
 2| 9
 2| 14
```

I want to produce a final dataframe like this

```
machine_id  | value | diff 
 1| 5| 1
 1| 3| -1
 2| 6| -4
 2| 10| 0
 2| 14| 4
```

the values in "diff" column is computed as `groupBy($"machine_id").avg($"value") - value`.

note that the avg for `machine_id==1` is `(5+3)/2 = 4` and for `machine_id ==2` is `(6+10+14)/3 = 10` 
What is the best way to produce such a final dataframe in Apache Spark?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Window` function to get the desired output

Given the dataframe as

```
+----------+-----+
|machine_id|value|
+----------+-----+
|1         |5    |
|1         |3    |
|2         |6    |
|2         |10   |
|2         |14   |
+----------+-----+
```

You can use following code

```
df.withColumn("diff", avg("value").over(Window.partitionBy("machine_id")))
    .withColumn("diff", 'value - 'diff)
```

to get the final result as

```
+----------+-----+----+
|machine_id|value|diff|
+----------+-----+----+
|1         |5    |1.0 |
|1         |3    |-1.0|
|2         |6    |-4.0|
|2         |10   |0.0 |
|2         |14   |4.0 |
+----------+-----+----+
```